# Making Servlet 2.5 code Servlet 3.0 compatible and vice versa

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I have a class that implements javax.servlet.Filter and inside that filter, I'm instantiating an instance of InterceptHttpRequestFilter and InterceptHttpResponseFilter (which are used to modify the incoming and outgoing request and response)

Example:

```
public class InterceptHttpRequestFilter implements HttpServletRequest {

    private HttpServletRequest httpReq;
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    public InterceptHttpRequestFilter(ServletRequest request) {
        this.httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        try {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), sw);
            sb.append(sw.getBuffer().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ....
```

When deploying this project on Tomcat6 using Servlet 2.5, everything works as it should.
Deploy it on Tomcat 7 and I get an AbstractMethodError:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [_______] in context with path [/__________-1.0.0] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.mycee.project.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The obvious solution is to implement all the missing methods required by Servlet Version 3's HttpRequest / Response interfaces.

The maven dependency on mvnrepository is still in alpha:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>
```

So my question is, does middle ground exist that will allow me to run this project on both Tomcat6 (Servlet 2.5) and Tomcat7 (Servlet 3.0) without having to tinker with my InterceptHttpRequestFilter and InterceptHttpResponseFilter ?

Comment: Apart from restricting yourself to using 2.5 and not use 3.0 methods, I don't see...

Comment: I don't quite understand this. Which abstract method is giving you trouble and on what class? is `MyFilter` in the trace your `InterceptHttpRequestFilter`? AFAIK you should be able to use 2.5 `Filter`'s just fine in a 3.0 container.

Comment: @Anders, the problem is not the filter but the Interceptors that implements HttpServletRequest / Response and that the containers are using different versions of the servlet specification. axtavt's solution to use HttpServletRequestWrapper solves this problem by filling in the missing methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's why it's recommended to extend `HttpServletRequestWrapper` instead of implementing `HttpServletRequest` directly.

`HttpServletRequestWrapper` has implementations of all required methods, therefore it should solve the problem.

Comment: Never knew about HttpServletRequestWrapper and HttpServletResponseWrapper - a pretty neat solution, allows me to get rid of most of the @Overrides :-)

Comment: Learned something new today ! +1